# c# проигрывание видео с YouTube

Tags: c#, видео, youtube

Давно думаю о том чтобы сделать приложение  (пару раз делал и всегда останавливался на том как же проиграть само видео .. ) чтобы смотреть видео в YouTube -

1. без рекламы
2. без рекомендаций и чего ещё лишнего ..
3. без не нужной телеметрии

и так можно продолжать долго ..
В общем есть два способа это делать

1. загружать видео используя YouTube Api но при этом в бесплатном варианте количество запросов сильно ограничено, а платный не подходит ..
2. парсить страницу с видео и выбирать с него ссылку "blob:http:// .... "

так вот парсить у меня выходит, а вот как правильно таким образом проиграть видео с YouTube мне не понятно.
ещё думаю что это в итоге снизит нагрузку на компьютер (чисто интересно будет ли в этом такой толк .. )

Прошу не предлагать использовать плагины для браузеров , я в курсе что есть такие сервисы как savefrom.net и прочие ..

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112820/discussion-on-question-by-getyoufun-c----youtube).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ну чтож вы так, YouTube популярная площадка, которую изучили уже все вдоль и поперек, а это означает, что есть инструменты, которые позволяют делать с ним все, что вы хотите.

Открываем NuGet и ищем там по ключевому слову [`youtube`](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=youtube) нужное нам решение, получаем это:

[image: NuGet]

Видим, что первым идет официальная библиотека для работы с API, не совсем то, что нам нужно. Далее идет некий `YoutubeExtractor`, но последнее его обноелвение было в 2016 году, что тоже не есть хорошо. Затем идет `YoutubeExplode`, обновлялся месяц назад. много загрузок, попробуем?

- Устанавливаем `YoutubeExplode` и смотрим попутно их [GitHub](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode) страничку.
- Узнав как работает библиотека, понимаем, что нам нужен некий `YoutubeClient()`, через который и пойдет вся работа. Заметьте, что он может быть сознан на основе уже существующего `HttpClient`, это важно! Дело в том, что `HttpClient` должен быть один на все приложение, иначе возникнет утечка соединений и ряд других проблем (можете почитать например [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/424873/)).

Далее я просто приведу ряд примеров по работе с данной библиотекой.

#### Получаем информацию о видео

Задача простая: Имея ссылку, получить информацию о видео (описание, теги, автор, название и др.).

```
var video = await client.Videos.GetAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1La4QzGeaaQ");
Console.WriteLine($"Название: {video.Title}");
Console.WriteLine($"Продолжительность: {video.Duration}");
Console.WriteLine($"Автор: {video.Author}");
```

Тут пока все просто, мы у ранее созданного `YoutubeClient()` запрашиваем информацию о видео, `URL` которого будет тот, что мы указали.

Результат:

```
Название: Peru 8K HDR 60FPS (FUHD)
Продолжительность: 00:05:38
Автор: Jacob + Katie Schwarz
```

#### Получаем `Stream` нужного видео

Задача: Получить некий "поток" нужного нам видео, который в последующем мы можем обработать так, как нам надо.

```
var streamManifest = await client.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1La4QzGeaaQ");
var streamInfo = streamManifest.GetMuxed().WithHighestVideoQuality();
```

Что тут происходит:

- Мы просим у ранее созданного клиента манифест потока, это некий объект, который содержит в себе список всех доступных потоков для указанного видео. Сами потоки могут быть разные (только аудио, только видео, ну и каждый под разное качество). Тут стоит учесть, тот факт, что библиотека, к сожалению, не всегда может получить максимальное качество видео, иногда 720 это ее максимум.
- `GetMuxed()` - как я сказал выше, youtube может дать нам только аудио, только видео, либо все вместе, вот `GetMuxed()` и делает последнее, он берет коллекцию потоков, которые содержат и видео и аудио.
- Так, как мы получили коллекцию потоков, то нам надо выбрать только один. Для таких целей есть `WithHighestVideoQuality()` - этот метод берет из списка один поток максимально доступного качества.

#### Получаем прямую ссылку на видео

Задача: Получить ссылку для прямого просмотра видео.

Ну, тут все просто, ибо как брать нужный поток мы узнали выше, а сам поток уже содержит в себе свойство `Url`. Но есть одна загвоздка, метод `WithHighestVideoQuality()` отдает нам `IVideoStreamInfo`, обобщенный интерфейс, и вот нам надо объект преобразовать в нужный класс. Всего их на сколько я знаю, [3](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/tree/master/YoutubeExplode/Videos/Streams):

1. `AudioOnlyStreamInfo()`
2. `VideoOnlyStreamInfo()`
3. `MuxedStreamInfo()`

Какой и для чего, я думаю и так понятно. Я же в своем примере выберу последний, ибо мы брали видео + аудио, а вам, если будет выбор, то стоит наверно делать проверку (например: `if(streamInfo is AudioOnlyStreamInfo audioOnlyStream)`). Я у себя просто преобразую в нужный тип:

```
var streamInfo = (MuxedStreamInfo)streamManifest.GetMuxed().WithHighestVideoQuality();
//var link = streamInfo.Url;
```

Далее мы можем получить нужные данные этого потока.
<sup>P.S. Для получения именно `URL` не надо делать преобразования, тут я лишь показал для примера как быть с разными потоками.</sup>

Результат (WPF - MediaElement):

[image: WPF MediaElement]

#### Скачиваем файл

Задача: Сохранить видео на диске.

```
var progress = new Progress<double>();
progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"Загружено: {e:P2}");

await client.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(streamInfo, $"video.{streamInfo.Container}", progress);
```

Пояснение:

- Мы у клиента вызываем `DownloadAsync()`, который требует от нас:

  - Ранее полученный поток с нужным качеством.
  - Путь, куда сохранять.
  - (не обязательно) `IProgress<double>`, который покажет процент загруженности данного файла.
  - (не обязательно) `CancellationToken`, который позволит отменить `Task`.

Обратите внимание на `streamInfo.Container` - это какое расширение должно быть у файла (в моем случае это `.mp4`.

Собственно на этом и все, основное я показал, а всякие плейлисты и прочие приблуды я думаю вы и сами познаете. Удачи!

---

Изучив немного библиотеку, я выяснил, что получить видео довольно просто, делается в пару шагов:

1. Мы делаем строку вида `https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/{videoId}`, она понадобиться для составления основного адреса.
2. Составляем основной URL, который должен выглядеть так: `https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={videoId}&el=embedded&eurl={eurl}&hl=en`, где `eurl`, это ссылка полученная в первом пункте. Это нам даст примерно такое: `https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=CZTCciHE72I&el=embedded&eurl=https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/CZTCciHE72I&hl=en`.
3. Переходим по этому адресу и в ответ получаем файл с информацией о видео. Информация там в виде `URL` строки (или нечто такого), по этому можем смело заменять `&` на новую строку, что даст нам такой результат:

   [image: Video Info]
4. Примерно в конце, будет ооочень длинная строка, которая является JSON данными, она то нам и нужна.
5. Изучив данный JSON мы можем получить кучу интересного про видео, включая и ссылку:

   [image: Video JSON]

Это я описал лишь [этот](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/blob/master/YoutubeExplode/ReverseEngineering/Responses/VideoInfoResponse.cs#L125) участок кода, который может помочь написать свое решение, "отрезав" лишнее из библиотеки. Так что уже дальше сами думайте, что делать с этими данными.

Comment: Отличный ответ, но кмк проще 199 за прем подписку заплатить. Тем более, оно сегодня работает, завтра - нет. Гуглы постоянно что-то подкручивают для защиты от скачиваний.

Comment: эм.. что я делаю не так? при назначении MediaElement   Player.Source = new Uri(streamInfo.Url);  пишет System.NullReferenceException проверяю ссылку - она не пустая и рабочая отчего такая ошибка? я проверяю в C# WPF может в этом дело?

Comment: @GetYouFun Значит у вас что-то другое `NULL`, из приведенного вами кода предположу, что `Player`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну Player лежит на форме (тип указал чтобы было понятно что за плеер .. т.е. это не определение переменной) и не равен NULL .. а выполняю код после загрузки формы

Comment: @GetYouFun Простите, а мне сейчас надо гадать что у вас там является `NULL`, или вы поставите брекпоинт и сами глянете?) Как я вам по той строке выше могу помочь то? P.S. В WPF нет "форм", есть "окна".  `а выполняю код после загрузки формы` - надеюсь после `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я конечно не прошу угадать, просто спросил , вдруг сталкивались с подобным .. ошибка появляется только при назначении источника, и выполняю код конечно после инициализации и даже после Loaded  .. разницы никакой. тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702505/playing-media-from-https-site-in-media-element-throwing-null-reference-exception пишут что MediaElement не работает с HTTPS ссылками, думал может в этом проблема, но у вас открылось же..

Comment: @GetYouFun Хм, знаете почему работает у меня? Потому, что мой WPF базируется на .NET Core. Там нету описанного вами бага с HTTPS. Как решить, увы, я не знаю. По ссылке выше там есть `MediaElementWithHttpClient`, попробуйте может его.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а, ясно спасибо за содействие

Comment: @aepot Кстати не соглашусь. За последние хм, лет 10, у них было только одно кардинальное изменение, после которого все программы по типу этой перестали работать, умельцы за пару дней наладили работоспособность. Так что не думаю, что данный вариант "завтра" прикроется. А по поводу "проще" - ну, кому как, я лично не хочу отдавать свои средства за то, что обязано быть бесплатным. Тут по сути как вон с Apple техникой, вы ее покупаете за бешенные деньги, она работает, причем хорошо, но только вы становитесь заложником системы и получаете массу ограничений и тут уже каждый сам решает, что ему надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ только хотел сказать что библиотека слишком массивная по количество подключаемых dll  и что сделал вручную , и только тогда увидел что вы это уже предложили :) вот только https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id= сделано для iframe вроде как, т.е. не будет так что если видео запрещено для встраивания то нечего не получу по такой ссылке ..

Comment: @GetYouFun По поводу "массивная", ну, как посмотреть) Я например, все свои проекты пакую в один .exe файл и мне лично по барабану сколько там у меня подключенных .dll, тем более, от Microsoft (а именно они там и подключаются). Вообще, переходите на .NET Core, он из коробки это все имеет и подключится от силы 1-2 dll. По поводу запрета встраивания, да, согласен, но я это написал как пример, который быстро бросился в глаза, для многих он может быть полезным. Библиотека кстати отдает ссылку для таких видео, значит если лучше изучить, то думаю можно найти как она это делает, я дальше не изучал.

Comment: @GetYouFun Нашел как это работает, тоже довольно просто. По сути, стартовой точкой можно считать [этот](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/blob/master/YoutubeExplode/Videos/Streams/StreamsClient.cs#L243) метод (да и весь класс), там видно, что идет изначально попытка получить данные из VideoInfo (Embed страница, либо то, что я описал в ответе), но если это не удалось, то идет запрос на [страницу просмотра](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/blob/master/YoutubeExplode/ReverseEngineering/Responses/WatchPage.cs#L106) видео, а там уже в коде страницы есть тот же JSON с URL.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно ли заставить MediaElement проигрывать Webm из byte[] (загруженное видео в память) или NetworkStream (загружающий видео по прямой ссылке) ?

Comment: @Blackmeser На Framework - нет, он ограничен. На .NET Core (и выше) - память и `Stream` не знаю, не пробовал, надо копаться во внутренностях, может можно переопределить (по умолчанию требует источник в виде `Uri`). `загружающий видео по прямой ссылке` - можно сразу указать эту ссылку как источник, он воспроизведет. Например, в этом ответе была строка по типу `mediaElement.Source = new Uri(link);`, где `link`, это `streamInfo.Url`, прямая ссылка на видео от ютуба, полученная при помощи библиотеки.

Comment: В форматом данных я тогда могу что-нибудь придумать, но главный вопрос в MediaElement + Webm, можно ли заставить проигрывать?

Comment: @Blackmeser Вы могли ведь и сами это проверить) Ну ок, простой тест `this.Content = new MediaElement() { Source = new Uri("https://dl8.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm") };`, проект .NET5, видео успешно воспроизвело.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо больше, не знал про этот компонент, второй месяц ковырял кривые VLC, а тут решение под рукой. Буду ковырять его, может получиться из byte[] читать. Тогда было бы вообще идеально. А если к нему ещё хоть как-то можно подключить ffdshow - я про MPC-HC забуду, а если и AviSync - то и PotPlayer выброшу =)