# Воспроизведение видеороликов на HTML странице в элементе WebBrowser WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, webbrowser

Создал на окне элемент WebBrowser, в отдельную папку закинул готовые html страницы, в которых есть html код видеороликов с ютуба, однако при переходе на данные страницы ни один из них не загружается по непонятной мне причине, хотя при открытии страниц через любой браузер они воспроизводятся нормально. Связано ли это как-то с версией браузера Internet Explorer? И если да, то как это исправить? Вот так видеоролик отображается на странице, если открывать через любой другой браузер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так в браузере в программе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример HTML кода видеоролика

```
<iframe 
width="560" 
height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bpASbXwjSp4?controls=0&amp;start=1" 
title="YouTube video player" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; 
autoplay; 
clipboard-write; 
encrypted-media; 
gyroscope; 
picture-in-picture" 
"allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: `WebBrowser` - это ужасный, кастрированный до жути элемент, он пригоден лишь вывести небольшой текст, не более. Нужен браузер - берите альтернативу более современную. Также, зачем вам тут вообще браузер? Хотите просмотр YouTube в WPF, берите прямую ссылку и воспроизводите ([показывал тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176039/220553)).

Comment: Я в качестве браузера использовал развивающийся `WebView2` ([тык](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/)), с моими задачами, где был нужен именно браузер, он справился на отлично. Что по поводу `WebBrowser` - он Internet Explorer 11, сам устарел, снят с поддержки и отправлен на пенсию, а так же ныне признан несовместимым с интернетом. Дайте ему покоиться с миром.