# Воспроизведение видео по ссылке C#

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть wpf MVVM приложение. Есть ссылки на видео. Я хочу открывать плеер и в нем проигрывать видео. Но вопрос - как?

Comment: Какая ссылка, на что? Ведь там может быть по ссылке все что угодно, от прямой ссылки на видео (тут уже зависит что за формат), а может быть аналог ютуба, где видео в неком контейнере, из которого все надо вытаскивать.

Comment: Ссылка на какой-то сервис? Прямая ссылка на видео, которое залито на какой-то видеосервис? Если ссылка для ютуба - у него есть своё апи (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs), с помощью которого можно получать информацию о видео и тд. Выводить видео в WebBrowser (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Нашел пример с готовым кодом - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF (не тестировал)

Comment: @Frehzy WebBrowser, IE, серьезно? Бросьте эту бяку, забудьте про нее, как про страшный сон. Если видео с ютуба, то там все в разы проще, даже API не нужно? Можете глянуть [мой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176039/220553) ответ. Если чет другое, то опятьже, есть VLC, который сожрет кучу форматов без каких либо проблем (если это не сделает стандартный плеер), но уж точно не использовать IE браузер, который уже давно устаревший в C# является (не знаю почему его не выпелили еще)...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я пользовался выводом видео один единственный раз, когда года 3 назад только начал изучать c# и тыкался во всех его приколах. После этого даже не трогал эту тему. Вот и написал первое, что вспомнил :D Даже не знал, что ютуб запилили свой пакет. Это в разы должно облегчить решение вопроса. Вижу даже, что у вас там по ссылке уже готовое решение. Автору даже ничего особо делать не придётся

Comment: @Frehzy Это не официальный пакет. А так, ну сами подумайте, воспроизводить видео через браузер... Не кажется странным? Как по мне, очень странно. Вот у вас на компьютере лежит например видео файл, фильм, вы его открываете через тот же Chrome или что у вас там? Я думаю нет, у вас есть для этого специальный плеер, отдельный софт, который предназначен именно для видео. Ну так чем C# приложение отличается от любого другого? Все также, для видео одно, для сайтов другое. Так что, лично для меня, ваш совет является очень странным...

Comment: @Frehzy WebBrowser - это конечно перебор. Первую причину Евгений указал, вторая - есть же WebView2 уже давно.