# Как спарсить количество подписчиков с YouTube канала

Tags: c#, парсер

Хочу сделать так, чтобы парсилось кол-во подписчиков на канале, но не знаю как.

```
try
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string LoadString = link;
    string resp = web.DownloadString(LoadString);

    //File.WriteAllText("Query.html", resp, Encoding.UTF8);
    //Process.Start("Query.html");

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(resp);


    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode hus = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"subscriber-count\"]");


    string htmlNode = hus.InnerText;
    //WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    //var html = wc.DownloadString("https://www.youtube.com/c/КаналЯла/about");

    //var match = Regex.Match(html, "var ytInitialData = ({.+?})</script>");
    //var json = match.Groups[1].Value;

    MessageBox.Show(htmlNode);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No");
}
```

Но вылазит такая ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Ссылка, по который будет загружаться html и парситься инфа такая: https://www.youtube.com/c/ITKAMASUTRA/about

Comment: 1. `WebClient` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`. 2. Не ориентируйтесь на HTML, что видите в браузере, скопируйте себе в блокнот значение `resp` и по нему уже пишите парсер, если не видите там нужное, то смотрите как и когда браузер это все получает. 3. У YouTube есть API, который даст вам все даннные без лишнего геморроя, советую использовать его! 4. Есть готовые библиотеки, которые получат за вас всю нужную информацию, одна из них YoutubeExplode, где вызовом нескольких методов вы можете получить нужное ([даже прямую ссылку на видео](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176039/220553)).

Comment: А можете пример с либой написать, я не могу найти методы, которые могут парсить подписчиков

Comment: А то я вообще не могу сообразить, как это сделать, только начал заниматься в этой сфере

Comment: Хм, проверил библиотеку, странно, чет думал, что там есть все о канале, оказывается нет. Скорей всего причина в том, что точное число подписчиков у ютуба скрыты, есть округленное (161 тыс. например), ну а оно находится в JSON, что внутри HTML, вы кстати на верном пути, `Regex.Match(html, "var ytInitialData = ({.+?})</script>");`, только не `</script>`, а `;</script>`, ибо JSON чуть раньше заканчивается там. Ну а из JSON уже тогда и берите то, что [надо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBvza.png).