# Как скачать файл с ютуба в формате mp3 на c# для отправки через телеграм бота?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, mp3

Я пишу бота для телеграмм, который будет скачивать песню с ютуба по ссылке. Я смог реализовать скачивание видео через YouTubeExtract, но не понимаю как скачать именно аудио. Оно должно сохраняться в переменную типа Stream, чтобы ее принял метод телеграма SendAudioAsync.

Вот пример кода для отправки сообщения:

```
case InteractionType.DownloadSong:
                var aud = await _mediaDownloader.DownloadAudio(messageText);
                if (aud is null)
                {
                    sentMessage = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                        chatId: chatId,
                        text: "Ошибка при скачивании аудио.\nПопробуйте еще раз!",
                        cancellationToken: token
                    );
                }
                sentMessage = await bot.SendAudioAsync(
                    chatId: chatId,
                    audio: new InputFile(aud),
                    cancellationToken: token);
                break;
```

Вот пример моего функционала для скачивания видео:

```
public async Task<Stream?> DownloadVideo(string url)
    {
        using var service = Client.For(YouTube.Default);
        var video = await service.GetVideoAsync(url);
        return await video.StreamAsync();
    }
```

Comment: пример здесь есть https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

Comment: еще пример https://stackoverflow.com/q/39877884/12888024

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176039/220553

Comment: Не нашел в пример ответа на вопрос. Мне нужно отделить видеоряд от аудио, чтобы телеграм показал пользователю только аудио файл. Он не должен никуда сохраняться на сервер. Мне нужно получить либо ссылку на скачивание, либо Stream звука.

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку, где идет работа с библиотекой, которая позволяет достать все, что угодно, как в виде ссылки, так и в виде потока, изучайте, пробуйте, а не смотрите что "там видео, а мне нужно аудио".